# Generate several instances by editing the master copy

Tags: excel, vba

This is a screenshot [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWyoi.jpg) of what I would like to change. In the picture the ### needs to be replaced by
N01
N02
N10 etc

This will be specified as required because it wont be in an order (can be N01, N05, N12 etc) and the rest needs to be copy pasted. This needs to be generated in a new worksheet.

The newly generated worksheet will have all the instances of N01, N02 etc populated together. Screenshot of the required result is given below [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdOrn.jpg)

Comment: Sorry but the dropbox links are broken. Moreover read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting questions

Comment: please edit your message to include the screenshot as a graphic. The dropbox link will probably become obsolete soon.

Comment: Sorry about the dropbox links. Replaced them with images. Please help me, I am in a tight spot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edits :)

Comment: thanks moderators for all the editing. Found the answer for my question. Cheers to me :P

Answer (score 0):

'Creates data as per the master data provided in row A2:T2. Creates 1-49 instances in "Replicated_Data" sheet and clears the content in "Master_Data" sheet

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "B01"
Range("A2").Select
SELECTION.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A50"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A50").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-55
Range("B2").Select
SELECTION.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B50"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B2:B50").Select
Range("A49").Select
SELECTION.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A49:A50"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A49:A50").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-60
Range("D2").Select
SELECTION.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D50"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("D2:D50").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-55
Range("E2").Select
SELECTION.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E50"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("E2:E50").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-45
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
Range("M2").Select
SELECTION.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M50"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("M2:M50").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-50
Range("R2").Select
SELECTION.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R50"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("R2:R50").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-55
Range("S2:T2").Select
SELECTION.Copy
Range("S3:T50").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-65
Range("N2:Q2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
SELECTION.Copy
Range("N3:Q50").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("J40").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-50
Range("F2:L2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
SELECTION.Copy
Range("F3:L50").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-70
Range("C2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
SELECTION.Copy
Range("C3:C50").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C52").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-75
Range("B2:T50").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
SELECTION.Copy
Sheets("Replicated_Data").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-40
ActiveSheet.Paste
SELECTION.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A2:Z1000").ClearContents
```

End Sub

'Copy data from "Replicated_Data" sheet to the "Test" sheet and clears contents in "Replicated_Data" sheet.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheets("Test").Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' then next free         row in sheet3 ("Test")
Sheets("Replicated_Data").Range("A1:T50").Copy
Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("A" & lastRow)
'Remove only the cell contents
Sheets("Replicated_Data").Select
SELECTION.ClearContents
```

End Sub